# odoo inheritance of view element without name or id

Tags: xpath, odoo-14

In odoo I try to change the recruitement form, but some of the stuctural elements dont have a name or id. When I change those elements it works fine initially, but when I upgrade the database then the rendering of the xml is stricter for some reason and gives an ParseError.

The recruitement form:

```
                <sheet>
                    <div class="oe_button_box" name="button_box"/>
                    <div class="oe_title">
                        <label for="name" class="oe_edit_only"/>
                        <h1><field name="name" placeholder="e.g. Sales Manager"/></h1>
                    </div>
                    <notebook> 
                        <page string="Job Description">
                            <div attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'recruit')]}">
                                <label for="description"/>
                                <field name="description" type="html"/>
                            </div>
                        </page>
                        <page name="description_page" string="Description">
                          <field name="description" type="html"/>
                          <div class="d-none oe_clear"/>
                        </page>
                        <page string="Recruitment">
                            <group>
                                <group name="recruitment">
                                    <field name="company_id" options="{'no_create': True}" groups="base.group_multi_company"/>
                                    <field name="department_id"/>
                                </group>
                                <group>
                                    <field name="no_of_recruitment"/>
                                </group>
                            </group>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
                </sheet>
```

As you can see; the sheet, notebook, pages and groups mostly dont have a name. The string attribute is also not sufficient to modify with a expression in xpath. So it feels like I'm just stuck with this framework.

What I try:

```
        <xpath expr="//sheet/notebook" position="replace">
            <notebook> 
                <page name="description_page" string="Description">
                    <field name="description" type="html"/>
                    <div class="d-none oe_clear"/>
                </page>
                <page string="Recruitment">
                    <group>
                        <group name="recruitment">
                            <field name="branch_concept" />
                            <field name="branch" />
                            <field name="department_id" />
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="no_of_recruitment"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </page>
            </notebook>
            </xpath>
```

And this works until I do a db upgrade, then I get a parseError.
Does anybody know I can use my own structure?

Comment: how about doing the workaround as follows? make an xpath to hide Job Description page and then make two another xpath which replace Recruitment and Description pages

Answer (score 0):

In the [xpath expression](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) you use `//<some_node>` to 'Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are'. You can also use `/<some_node>/<some_other_node>` to locate a specific element.
for example `/form/sheet/notebook/page[1]`